# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2' after changing `sys.path`

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, opencv

I have two python3 environments on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

1. The built-in Python environment at `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/` and
2. Anaconda python3. **Note: Opencv works perfectly in both of them.**

The system I am building need to use `sudo python3`(`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`) and `python3`(`anaconda`) at different times, but I want to minimize the dependency size for users. So what I am trying to do is that the dependencies will be installed in the built-in python3 only and when the program is called by normal `python3` the script will set the `sys.path` to the `sys.path` of `sudo python`.(I have stored that path in a file at the installation time.)

But when I do that `import cv2` raises: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2'`

**Note: Other libraries works fine. Only Opencv is having this problem.**

Comment: `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: I already have opencv installed!

Comment: try a easy way, move `import cv2` to the line before `import sys \n sys.path.append('...')`

Comment: I don't wont to have the Opencv in the anaconda python because I want to lower down the dependency size. And just to be sure, the line is `sys.path = ['...', '...', '...']` instead of `sys.path.append('...')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it was by installing OpenCV using `sudo apt install python3-opencv`. OpenCV installed with `apt install` can be used anywhere in your system whereas pip will only install OpenCV to a particular python environment.